# Updating a Jenkins job with the Groovy Jenkins API

Tags: api, groovy, jenkins

I'm looking at using the Groovy script console to create and update jobs on Jenkins. Using the API documented here

http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/

I've discovered how to create a job by using
    `createProjectFromXML(String name, InputStream xml)`

But this method will fail if the job already exists. How can I update an existing job with new xml?

**Update**

Based on @ogondza's answer I used the follow to create and then update a job

```
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*
import java.io.*
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*

config = """......My config.xml......"""

InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(config.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

job = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName("job_name", AbstractItem)

if (job == null) {
  println "Constructing job"
  Jenkins.getInstance().createProjectFromXML("job_name", stream);
}
else {
  println "Updating job"
  job.updateByXml(new StreamSource(stream));
}
```

Comment: What do you want to update in the job?

Comment: Anything. The buildsteps, tools installed, artifacts, SSHPlublisher settings, etc. I already have these settings in xml and I want to update the job if the xml changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [AbstractItem#updateByXml](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractItem.html#updateByXml(javax.xml.transform.Source)) for updating. Also note that you can create/update jobs by XML using REST API and Jenkins CLI.

Comment: Currently I'm using the REST API via python to update the jobs. But it is too slow. To update 40 jobs takes ~6 - 7 minutes. With groovy I believe I can reduce that to ~1 minute.

Comment: Can you suggest how I can access this method? Jenkins.instance.getProjects() returns Project objects which inherit from AbstractItem. But it's depreciated. Instead the recommendation is to use getAllItems()/getItem() which return TopLevelItem objects. This class does not inherit from AbstractItem but it has sub-classes which do. But forced casting seems like a bad way to organize an API.

Comment: Use `Jenkins#getAllItems(Class<T>)` or `Jenkins#getItemByFullName(String fullName, Class<T>)` to restrict the selection to only those types you know you can manipulate. It would be `AbstractItem` in this case.