# How to set auth token programatically in init.groovy.d for a job to trigger builds remotely

Tags: jenkins

I am able to use `Jenkins.instance.getJob('job-name').getAuthToken()` in order to get the auth token that is already saved for the job. But I didn't find any setter function to set that value. Nor do I know how to actually enable the `Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)` option programatically. The code online is erratic at best (for me that is). Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.[image: The setting that I need to change programatically]

Comment: are you using pipeline scripting?

Comment: yes in the example that i posted, I am using a pipeline based job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried editing the config file of the job [using this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272288/updating-a-jenkins-job-with-the-groovy-jenkins-api). Then I found out I could do the following:

```
    AbstractItem it = (AbstractItem)Jenkins.getInstance().getItem('url-trigger-test')
    if(it.authToken instanceof hudson.model.BuildAuthorizationToken) {
      println(it.authToken.getToken())
      it.authToken = new hudson.model.BuildAuthorizationToken('anotherToken')
      it.save()
    }
```

Hope this helps someone. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

give this a look.

```
job('example') {
    authenticationToken('secret')
}
```

Source:
https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.FreeStyleJob.authenticationToken

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).